# Not sure how to properly use variables and use them in if statements in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, iptables, fail2ban

I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to properly declare variables in bash scripting and how to use them further on in my program. What I wish to accomplish is to store the IP address of a blocked IP in a variable. I wish to use iptables -S INPUT [line number] to do this. Furthermore I wish to check if this IP address i identical too another IP address to then go ahead and change the iptables policy to ACCEPT if it is indeed the same address.

The problem that I am having is that I have such little experience with bash scripting that I am not really sure at all why my script doesn't work or what I can change to make it work.

Hoping for any experienced shell scripters there who could help me :)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Getting an IP address from a saved database
IP_ADDRESS=$(echo "${line%%,*}")

# Defining the line number for iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers while reading list
LINE_NUMBER=$(echo "$iptables_line" | cut -d " " -f1)

IPSTATUS_LINE_NUMBER=$(echo "$LINE_NUMBER")

# Wanting to store the IP address from iptables -S INPUT here to use for later
LINE_FROM_IPSTATUS=$(echo "iptables -S INPUT $IPSTATUS_LINE_NUMBER" | grep "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+")   ############### Error is here
                
echo "IP imported from iptables -S => $LINE_FROM_IPSTATUS"

# Check if the IP address is on the iptables -S line
    if [ "$LINE_FROM_IPSTATUS" = "$IP_ADDRESS" ]; then ### Potential second error here

        echo "IP: $IP_ADDRESS was located on line nr. $LINE_NUMBER"
        
        # Changing the rule in INPUT Chain to ACCEPT
        iptables -R INPUT "$LINE_NUMBER" -s "$IP_ADDRESS" -j ACCEPT
    else
        # Echo if something went wrong
        echo "Oops. Something went wrong"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks good overall, but you don't need to use `$(echo ... )` for every variable assignment. For example, these are sufficient to assign  IP_ADDRESS and IPSTATUS_LINE_NUMBER,

```
IP_ADDRESS="${line%%,*}"

IPSTATUS_LINE_NUMBER="$LINE_NUMBER"
```

On the line where your error is happening, try calling `iptables` inside the command substitution instead of echo-ing the command and args,

```
LINE_FROM_IPSTATUS=$(iptables -S INPUT $IPSTATUS_LINE_NUMBER | grep "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+")
```